# WPF Organization Tree/Chart Control or hookup?

Tags: wpf, charts

Q1. Which would be the best resource or tutorial to setup a simple WPF Organization Chart or Tree for an organization object (self referencing).I would like to have a button when clicked which would show an organization chart (hierarchical) tree of the various departments and sub-department.I'm looking for a base to start code + control.

Q2.Are there any report software like Crystal Report or WPF that could render something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: [1 link from a blog](http://wpfblog.info/2008/05/27/wpf-treeview-org-chart-a-bit-of-refactoring/)   
[Archived Version of above from Wayback](http://web.archive.org/web/20090520093457/http://wpfblog.info/2008/05/27/wpf-treeview-org-chart-a-bit-of-refactoring/)

[Another one from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomTreeViewLayout.aspx)

Q2: [Commercial printing control](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ReportsWPF/)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Family.Show](https://web.archive.org/web/20180726053755/http://www.vertigo.com:80/familyshow.aspx) which has a very nice genealogical diagram. It's not an out of the box solution for making an organizational chart, but it's a good example how to do it. The source code is available on [CodePlex](https://web.archive.org/web/20100311235859/http://www.codeplex.com:80/familyshow).

[image]

Comment: Based on the Family.Show code ActiveDirectory.Show(http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/activedirectoryshow)

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but, Infragistics has an org chart WPF control as well.

[Infragistics Org Chart](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/wpf/org-chart/overview)

[image]